# What is the correct soup.find() command?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape the racename ('The Valley R2') and the horse name ('Ronniejay') from the following website https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/form-finder/e2a0f7e13bf0057b4c156aea23019b18.

What is the correct soup.find() code to do this.

My code to get the race name:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
source = requests.get('https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/form-finder/e2a0f7e13bf0057b4c156aea23019b18').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
race = soup.find('h3')
print(race)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website uses JavaScript, but `requests` doesn't support it. We can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) as an alternative to scrape the page.

Install it with: `pip install selenium`.

Download the correct ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

URL = "https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/form-finder/e2a0f7e13bf0057b4c156aea23019b18"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(URL)
# Wait for page to fully render
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

race_name = soup.select_one(".form-result-group__event span").text
horse_name = "".join(
    x for x in soup.select_one(".form-result__competitor-name").text if x.isalpha()
)

print(race_name)
print(horse_name)

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
The Valley R2
Ronniejay
```